# change spinner drop down width in monodroid xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to reduce Xamarin monodroid spinner drop down width but its not working for me.it's still popping on full screen width. can anyone help where i am going wrong.

following is the spinner.

```
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:dropDownWidth="50dp"
        android:minWidth="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe this solves your problem

```
android:spinnerMode=""
```